# How do I provide my access_token with python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, authorization

```
request = requests.get(f"https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/{id}")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqrsw.png

Is there a way to do this with requests?

Comment: Yes, requests can do this.  But you have to know how the api expects to receive  the token -- in a header, or a query argument, or post data, or some other way?  I'm sure the api documentation will tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this `https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/reference/payments/_payments_id/get` you need to provide a header with your access token you get through OAUTH. And then once you get the access token, you can do

```
header = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + "your access token"}
result = requests.get(f"https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/{id}", headers=header)
```

which will return you a json result